# How to make upper letter in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"car":["mazda", "audi", "audi", "bmw", "mazda"]})
```

I would like to have all values like for instance: mazda, audi and so on from big letter at the beginning. So I want to have for example not mazda but Mazda, this operation I would like to make on the whole values in "car" Serie.

Comment: With a modicum of effort: [`str.capitalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.str.capitalize(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html#pandas.Series.str.capitalize) for that:

```
data['car'] = data['car'].str.capitalize()
```

This then gives us:

```
>>> data
     car
0  Mazda
1   Audi
2   Audi
3    Bmw
4  Mazda
```

Comment: It works! but If I use column "car" in further plots I still have small letterts at the beginning, why ?